# Rationale behind __lt field lookup in Django's DateFieldListFilter

Tags: django, query-optimization, django-queryset

What is the idea behind Django's admin filter DateFieldListFilter adding an __lt query for future dates? See excerpt below:

```
self.lookup_kwarg_since = '%s__gte' % field_path
self.lookup_kwarg_until = '%s__lt' % field_path

...

self.links = (_('This year'), {
                self.lookup_kwarg_since: str(today.replace(month=1, day=1)),
                self.lookup_kwarg_until: str(next_year),
            })
```

For one, I don't see the need to add `next_year` to the search here, wouldn't `tomorrow` (this one actually is there for a daily search and a 7-day search) or something like `end_of_the_day` be enough? It seems very arbitrary and unnecessary to me.

Secondly, wouldn't just having a `__gte` query without `__lt` faster? Or, perhaps, even using `__range` when the dataset is smaller could improve the search performance.

Comment: It is not a filter for future dates, it is a filter for dates with "This year", then it really makes sense does it not?

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat I see, that makes sense if you take "This year" very literally, from the first day of the year to the date lower than the first day of the next year. I understood "This year" as more of "from the beginnning of the year till now", where I think the query could then be optimized. But you are right, it does indeed make sense. Thanks!